# Show Keyboard dynamically in ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to display keyboard in ionic dynamically with no luck. I have a text field like

```
<input type="search"  placeholder="Search" ng-change="onSearchChange()" ng-click="clicked()" ng-model="searchVal"  id="MyField" ng-controller="searchCtrl" >
```

in clicked function i am navigation to new page like

```
 $state.go("tabs.searchresult");
```

but there is no keyboard on next page. I want to show keyboard on searchresult.

Comment: You will have to focus on input field in next page. So keyboard will be shown automatically.

Comment: it has already focus on it (and if i had to do that dynamically how to do that)?

Answer (score 0):

@nOmi: As my understanding.

1. You are in the search page has a search box with id = MyField, then you type a keyword. After touch to tap icon or tap enter, it will go to search result page.
2. In search result page, it also have an input with id = MyField in the top with result below. And you also want to show the keyboard.

If it is, please do so.

```
$state.go('tabs.searchresult').then(function() {
  $('#MyField').focus();//YOU WILL NEED JQUERY FOR THAT ONE.
});
```

If in the search result page doesn't have any text box. You need to install [ionic keyboard plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) to trigger show keyboard dynamically.

The script will be

```
$state.go('tabs.searchresult').then(function() {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
});
```

Comment: my search field is in header it is same on both pages. i tried focusing the field , field got focused but the keyboard doesn't show . I tried adding keyboard plugin but it gives me error cordova not defined. But cordova.js is in my index.html file.

Comment: So when change to search result state, the input have already been focused but no keyboard.
For keyboard plugin, where did you get a problem and can give me a bit detail ?

Comment: i added the plugin and called the show method as you said on browser it says "ReferenceError: cordova is not defined". but cordova.js is in index.html, and on device it do nothing.

Comment: @nOmi: It won't be worked If you are using browser to test. You have to deploy to a device and see the result. Which android you are using ?

Comment: i am using 4.4.2. (i knw about the browser but it is not working on device either)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117697/discussion-between-nomi-and-trungk18).